# How to join 2 lists

Tags: java, database, inner-join

I have created 2 tables(which i am reading from a 2 diffrent files ) and inserted values into lists .now i want to join table such that (I have attached image)

Record 1:Faculty SID    Faculty Courses F_Home Phone    H_Work Phone

Record 2; SID            Age            Home Phone Work Phone  PH No

Final: Faculty SID  Faculty Courses F_Home Phone    H_Work Phone    SID Age Home Phone  Work Phone  PH No

```
        while(s.hasNext())
        {  String field1=s1.next();
              String field=s.next();
            values.add(field);values1.add(field1);
         for(String x:values)
            {list1.add(x);

            }   
          for(String y:values1)
            {
                list2.add(y);
                }
        }  

       List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
       newArray.addAll(list1);
         newArray.addAll(list2);

for(int h=0;h<100;h++)
{
    System.out.printf("%s",newArray.get(h)+ "\n");

}
```

Comment: What are s, s1, values, value1, list1, list2? Can you give more context for that code, and at least the variables declaration?

Answer (score 4):

Use Guava's:

```
 Iterables.concat(Iterable<T>... list)
```

Guava could be included using maven:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I think what he is saying is that he has a 2 tables which he wants to join with a key, not just concatenating 2 lists.

Comment: @assylias: yes i want to join using first field how do i do it

Comment: What do you mean "using first field"?

Comment: @above what is Guava's Please tell me i don't know

Comment: the first column in 1 table is faculty SSN and first column in 2 table is StudentSSN. i need to perform join on that column

Comment: I hope you don't retrieve this lists from DB... What do you need at out? Collection<Collection<String>> collection of joined strings?

Comment: no i am not retriving from DB i am reading this data from a excel file.

Comment: I need a table after performing joins